# RegEx loop behaviour in TypeScript - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have strange problem with regex, im trying to check the user input in contentEditable div with regex, after each keydown, and if it match for example "hello" or "status", it should return modified text with `<span style="color: purple">hello<span>`. And it works properly with unique words, phrases or on paste, but when i declare both "hello" and "hello world" as key words, and type it in contentEditable, regex match only "hello", even if "hello world" is first in my array of strings.

Here is the code of my function:

```ts
searchByRegEx(wordsArr: string[],  sentence: string): string {

        let matchingWords = []; // matching words array

        wordsArr.forEach((label) => {
            const regEx = new RegExp(label, 'gi');
            regEx.lastIndex = 0
            let match = regEx.exec(sentence);
            while (match) {
                // console.log(match) - results of this console.log below
                matchingWords.push(match[0]);
                match = regEx.exec(sentence);
            }
        });

        matchingWords = matchingWords.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b.length - a.length;
        });

        matchingWords.forEach((word) => {
            sentence = sentence.replaceAll(
                word,
                `<span style='color:${InputColorsHighlightValue.PURPLE}'>${word}</span>`
            );
        });

        return sentence
    }
}
```

And here is how i use it:

```ts
 if (this.labels) {
            textToShow = this.searchByRegEx(['hello', 'hello world'], textToShow)
        }
```

This is how it looks in devTools, regex match properly, but ONLY on paste :

[image]

And here when i try to type it manually, it checks on every keydown, but cant match both hello and hello world. And as you can see, input in regex is the same as above:

[image]

I am struggling with this functionality and would appreciate any helpful advice.

[Live version in stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7tbb8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3AL5-L5)

Comment: Isn't that because you set `regEx.lastIndex = 0`? What is the purpose of setting that manually?

Comment: PS this has nothing to do with Typescript. Typescript only works with typings, the rest is just javascript.

Comment: I found that storing lastIndex value may couse that problem, so i tried to reset it manually, but it didnt solve it. That issue existst even if i remove line with regEx.lastIndex = 0.

Comment: Could you share the problematic regex?

Comment: You can find it in first image, this is how it looks. 
```const regEx = new RegExp(label, 'gi');```
The label is created dynamically with the value from the array, so when I pass "hello" and "hello world" it creates a regex with those values ​​in a loop

Comment: I understand, but the actual value of `label` is what matters as that's matched with the string.

Comment: Okay, so this is how it looks. I printed it in console.

For label hello the created regex is:
`/hello?/gi`

Comment: How are you passing the content of the contenteditable div to your function? This is an important part of the story.

Comment: Could not reproduce here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sma6zx?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I get content via getElementById, remove all the span tags, then pass it to angular service (with my functionality), return string modified with colors, and render it as innerHTML.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please add the surrounding code/HTML that is needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I reproduced this issue in stack blitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7tbb8b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3AL5-L5

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things wrong with the actual regex in your example. If `/hello?/gi` is your input for a regex, consider the following things:

- Your regex function already has those `gi` flags (`new RegExp(label, 'gi');`)
- There are two ways to use a regex in javascript, `new RegExp(regex)` or `/regex/`. When you put a regex between slashes `/hello/`, you use the second one. Don't combine these two, it won't work!
- You have a question mark on the single matchable part of your regex. This basically means that your regex does not have to match anything (and I don't know if your browser even knows how to process that correctly, I think the regex might be invalid). Since it should match either 'hello' or nothing at all, you should remove the `?` parameter.

If you just want to match a plain string, not a pattern, don't use regexes. You can, but it's unnecessary obfuscation and probably computationally more demanding (i.e. lower performance).